# Read from QTcpSocket without using readyRead() signal

Tags: c++, qt, qtcpsocket

I have a `QTcpSocket` that lives in different thread from GUI.
When using `readyRead()` signal by connecting it to some slot, things work.
But when I dont use it and run into a condition controlled `while(conditionControlVar)` with `msleep()` inside, `bytesAvailable()` always returns 0.
and yes my socket is in the same thread in which I am reading.

```
//when connection with Server is established
startReading();
...
void startReading()
{
    while(conditionVar)
    {
        qDebug()<<"Bytes Avl:"<<socket.bytesAvailable(); //Always Zero
        if(bytesAvailable < 8)
            thread()->msleep(50);
        else
        {
            //Read Data
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `waitForReadyRead(int msecs)` which blocks until new data is available for reading and the `readyRead()` signal has been emitted. The function will timeout after msecs milliseconds; the default timeout is 30000 milliseconds. It returns true if the there is new data available for reading; otherwise it returns false. So it can be like:

```
void startReading()
{
    while(conditionVar)
    { 
        if(socket->waitForReadyRead(50))
        {
            //Read Data
        }
    }
}
```

The socket should also be in the same thread as `startReading()` thread.